# Visual Studio Last 4 lines are wrong and I don´t know why

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

```
Public Class Form1
    Private _zkouska1 As New Bitmap("C:\Users\w\Desktop\zkouska1.gif")
    Private _zkouska2 As New Bitmap("C:\Users\w\Desktop\zkouska2.gif")

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnPaint(e)

        e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(New Bitmap(_zkouska1), 0, 0)
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        MyNewSub()
    End Sub

    Sub MyNewSub()
        BackColor = Color.Red
        TransparencyKey = BackColor
    End Sub
    Private Sub Example_ControlAdded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ControlEventArgs) Handles Me.ControlAdded

        AddHandler e.Control.MouseClick, AddressOf Example_MouseClick
    End Sub

    Private Sub Example_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseClick
        If True Then e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(New Bitmap(_zkouska2), 0, 0) = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting? The last 4 lines are fine, but we need more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't indicated specifically which lines are causing the issue, but the issue with this line:

```
If True Then e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(New Bitmap(_zkouska2), 0, 0) = True
```

is that MouseEventArgs doesn't have a Graphics member. Perhaps the thing to do here is to use the Mouse_Clicked event to set a variable that keeps tracks of whether the mouse was clicked (and where), and use the Paint event to do the actual drawing.

So you would add a boolean variable to the class:

```
Private _clicked As Boolean
```

Change the MouseClicked event to something like this:

```
Private Sub Example_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseClick
    _clicked = True
End Sub
```

Add a Paint event and make that event so it's something like this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Paint
    If _clicked Then
        e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(New Bitmap(_zkouska2), 0, 0)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, problem is in this line you mentioned. When I click on "zkouska1 graphics" I need to change automaticly this graphics to "zkouska2 graphics" and I am a new in VB, so I can´t figure out which code exactly I should use...

Comment: Clarified the answer a bit.